# NSImage size problem

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimage

I'm using the same image resource in two different controllers. In both controllers the image is shown in different sizes, the problem is that once the image is shown in a smaller size than the original, the next time I get the image by `[NSImage imageNamed:@"resource.png"]` the image size is set to the last size it took. I tried by invoking the recache method on NSImage and also tried to set the cache mode to any the posible value, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that

```
[NSImage imageNamed]
```

As you mentioned is in the cache, and as long as it is in the cache it will return the cached image so what you need to do is first released the previous reference or use the object's setName method and setting to nil. Here is the documentation reference:

The NSImage class may cache a reference to the returned image object for performance in some cases. However, the class holds onto cached objects only while the object exists. If the image object is subsequently released, either because its retain count was 0 or it was not referenced anywhere in a garbage-collected application, the object may be quietly removed from the cache. Thus, if you plan to hold onto a returned image object, you must retain it like you would any Cocoa object. **You can clear an image object from the cache explicitly by calling the object’s setName: method and passing nil for the image name.**

Answer (score 4):

You should never modify an instance of `NSImage` obtained from `imageNamed:`. The returned instance is shared with other clients, so it should not be changed.

If you have to `setSize:` on the image, just make a copy and use that one:

```
NSImage *image = [[[NSImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"] copy] autorelease];
[image setSize:(NSSize){128, 128}];
```